# Problem with POST request from APE server module

Tags: python, django, server-push, ajax-push, ape

I use Ajax Push Engine as push engine and Django for main site. I wrote the server
module which must send the request to my Django-based application when
new user join the channel by using Http module. My Django-based project runs on the local
machine on local.jjjbbb.org.

```
Ape.addEvent("join", function(user, channel) {
    var request = new Http('http://local.jjjbbb.org/test-
this/');    // this is a my test url
    request.set('method', 'POST');
    request.writeData('test-message', 'Hello APE!');

    request.getContent( function(result) {
        Ape.log(result);  // this code never work
    });

});
```

But this code doesn't work, request doesn't receive. When I change url
to anything else (like www.google.com or localhost for example) all
works correctly and I have a result. But when I try to send request to
my application request doesn't work. This problem is only when I try
to send request from server side, when I use jQuery for sending from
client side all works correctly.

Why I cannot send POST request from server side to my domain?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I already found my problem. APE works fine, it was a little trouble with CSRF protection in Django.